# Do not see .netStandard in list of available Targets

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-standard, visual-studio-2017

I am in visual studio 2017 and our team has other projects which are targetted against .netstandard framework but when I try to re-target my project to .netstandard then it does not show me option to choose .netstandard I only see .netCore 1.0 and 1.1. Why is that?

Comment: You simply created a wrong project type. Try to create a new .NET Standard Class Library and try again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Visual Studio tooling for .Net Standard/.Net Core still has some warts like that. If you create a .Net Core class library project, you won't be able to use the VS UI to change it to a .Net Standard project.

You can change it by editing the csproj manually, which is much easier with the improvements made in VS 2017:

- Right click on your project in the Solution Explorer and select "Edit YourProject.csproj".
- Change `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>` to e.g. `<TargetFramework>netstandard1.4</TargetFramework>`.
- That's it.

Also note that when you use the "Class Library (.NET Core)" template in VS 15.3 Preview, it actually creates a .Net Standard 2.0 library, since .Net Core class libraries should be fairly rare. But I don't know if the release version of VS 15.3 will behave the same.

Comment: There is one more change that may need to be done, `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` needs to be changed to `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` if he is currently targeting a .net core website and instead wants to target it as a library.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain When I create a new project using the "Class Library (.NET Core)" template, I don't get `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">`, so I'm not sure that needs to be changed.